# Why do top and ps show different PIDs for the same processes?

Tags: process-management, multithreading, pid

When I run `top -H`, I see that my multiple `mysql` threads all have the same PID. However, in `ps -eLf` I see each one has a different PID:

`ps -eLf`

```
UID        PID  PPID   LWP  C NLWP STIME TTY          TIME CMD
mysql     1424     1  1424  0   17 18:41 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld
mysql     1424     1  1481  0   17 18:41 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld
mysql     1424     1  1482  0   17 18:41 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld
mysql     1424     1  1483  0   17 18:41 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld
mysql     1424     1  1484  0   17 18:41 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld
mysql     1424     1  1485  0   17 18:41 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld
mysql     1424     1  1486  0   17 18:41 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld
mysql     1424     1  1487  0   17 18:41 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld
mysql     1424     1  1488  0   17 18:41 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld
mysql     1424     1  1489  0   17 18:41 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld
mysql     1424     1  1490  0   17 18:41 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld
mysql     1424     1  1791  0   17 18:41 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld
mysql     1424     1  1792  0   17 18:41 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld
mysql     1424     1  1793  0   17 18:41 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld
mysql     1424     1  1794  0   17 18:41 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld
mysql     1424     1  1809  0   17 18:41 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld
mysql     1424     1  1812  0   17 18:41 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld
```

and in `top -H`

```
PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S  %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
 1424 mysql     20   0  539m  56m 7200 S   0.0  1.5   0:00.08 mysqld                                                                  
 1481 mysql     20   0  539m  56m 7200 S   0.0  1.5   0:00.16 mysqld                                                                  
 1482 mysql     20   0  539m  56m 7200 S   0.0  1.5   0:00.33 mysqld                                                                  
 1483 mysql     20   0  539m  56m 7200 S   0.0  1.5   0:00.16 mysqld                                                                  
 1484 mysql     20   0  539m  56m 7200 S   0.0  1.5   0:00.23 mysqld                                                                  
 1485 mysql     20   0  539m  56m 7200 S   0.0  1.5   0:00.27 mysqld                                                                  
 1486 mysql     20   0  539m  56m 7200 S   0.0  1.5   0:00.15 mysqld                                                                  
 1487 mysql     20   0  539m  56m 7200 S   0.0  1.5   0:00.18 mysqld                                                                  
 1488 mysql     20   0  539m  56m 7200 S   0.0  1.5   0:00.16 mysqld                                                                  
 1489 mysql     20   0  539m  56m 7200 S   0.0  1.5   0:00.16 mysqld                                                                  
 1490 mysql     20   0  539m  56m 7200 S   0.0  1.5   0:00.34 mysqld                                                                  
 1791 mysql     20   0  539m  56m 7200 S   0.0  1.5   0:00.26 mysqld                                                                  
 1792 mysql     20   0  539m  56m 7200 S   0.0  1.5   0:00.54 mysqld                                                                  
 1793 mysql     20   0  539m  56m 7200 S   0.0  1.5   0:00.00 mysqld                                                                  
 1794 mysql     20   0  539m  56m 7200 S   0.0  1.5   0:00.00 mysqld                                                                  
 1809 mysql     20   0  539m  56m 7200 S   0.0  1.5   0:00.00 mysqld                                                                  
 1812 mysql     20   0  539m  56m 7200 S   0.0  1.5   0:00.13 mysqld
```

What is going on and which one should I believe?

Comment: Where is the question ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They are actually showing the same information in different ways. This is what the `-f` and `-L` options to `ps` do (from `man ps`, emphasis mine):

> -f                     Do full-format listing. This option can be combined with many
>   other UNIX-style options to add additional columns. It also causes the command arguments to be printed. **When used with -L, the NLWP (number of threads) and LWP (thread ID) columns will be added.**
>
> -L              Show threads, **possibly with LWP and NLWP columns.**
>
> tid              TID       the unique number representing a dispatacable entity (alias lwp, spid).  This value                   may also
>   appear as: a process ID (pid); a process group ID
>   (pgrp); a session ID for the 
>                     session leader (sid); a thread group ID for the thread group leader (tgid); and a tty 
>                     process group ID for the process group leader (tpgid).

---

So, `ps` will show thread IDs in the `LWP` column while the `PID` column is the actual *process identifier*.

`top` on the other hand, lists the different threads in the `PID` column though I can't find an explicit mention of this in `man top`.

Answer (score 2):

It's just a difference in presentation.  Look at the `LWP` column on your `ps` output -- `LWP` is `L`ight`W`eight `P`rocess.  The kernel can distinguish between a full process and a thread, but it still has to schedule them independently (that being the purpose of a thread) with the same mechanism it uses to schedule processes and so the id's the scheduler sees have to be unique, best achieved by having a single pool of process and thread id's for every purpose and using other ways to tell the two kinds apart.

Answer (score -2):

You see the parent process `1424`, a process that has created one or more child processes (`the other PIDs`).

Comment: They aren't child processes, they're kernel threads of the same process.